# React Unmet Dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

First I will explain my situation:
I added react-native-multiple-select-list package to my react-native project by running: 'yarn add react-native-multiple-select-list':

```
"dependencies": {
        "react-native-multiple-select-list": "^1.0.4"
}
```

The package react-native-multiple-select-list@1.0.4 has a dependency on react-native-vector-icons package:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^3.0.0"
},
```

The problem is that react-native-vector-icon@3.0.0 has unmet dependency with my react@16

I found on github that the on the new version (1.0.5) the issue was fixed and the version of react-native-vector-icons changed to 4.5 which is met with react@16

But this version (1.0.5) is not published yet to npm.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way you use the last github version?
- I tried to change manually the version of "react-native-vector-icons" to 4.5 and than run `yarn install` from inside the package. It works, but each time I run `yarn add` (no matter which package) it gets changed
  back the version to 3. Is there way to keep it on 4.5?

Thanks

Elad

Answer (score 0):

change dependencies inside package.json to your current version

```
"dependencies": {
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0"}
```

Comment: Hi Rijul. I did it but as I said each time I run yarn add (no matter which package) it changed back the version to 3.

Comment: Hmm, i guess yarn has cached your version 3 and that is why whenever you add it is adding the older version , try yarn cache clean react-native-vector-icons then do yarn add react-native-vector-icons@^4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't publish it yourself for the author, but you can publish it against your company's npm repo or your private one (maybe with a tool like [sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia)). If the author is not reacting (I see last commit from 23rd Jan and an open issue on this topic since 11th Feb), then this might be the best option if you absolutely need it working asap. If you publish it though, change the package name slightly so that it is clear that you diverged from the official releases.

For the second question, the **react-native-multiple-select-list@1.0.4** picks always version range `^3.0.0`, which excludes `^4.5.0` versions. Even if you install version 4 manually, the react-native-multiple-select-list@1.0.4 will pick version 3 (as specified in its package.json) and you just end up with two version of the icons in your node modules (with NPM5 one icon package on the root level, the other in react-native-multiple-select-list's node_modules).

Comment: Thanks Dan. I know that react-native-multiple-select-list@1.0.4 picks always version 3. My question was if there is any way to remark npm to not refresh this package when I add other package?

Comment: @user3674055 explain me pls what exactly means "to not refresh this package"? I am lost here.

Comment: Means that if I change the version by myself to 4.5 , after running yarn add , yarn pick up again the source of  react-native-multiple-select-list@1.0.4 from npm and than override my changes back to 3.

Comment: And where (or how?) do you change the version to 4.5 exactly?